# Do Jehovah’s Witnesses believe that demon possession is possible within their ranks?

Tags: jehovahs-witnesses, demons, demon-possession

**Do Jehovah’s Witnesses believe that demon possession is possible within their ranks?**

This question came about as a result of my answering this question: [Do Jehovah's Witnesses believe in exorcisms?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/83598/25495)

Is it possible for Jehovah’s Witnesses to become  possessed by demons (to the exclusion of obsession, oppression, exterior physical pain, infestation or subjection, which are seen as steps towards being truly possessed by a demon) or are they somehow immune to this possibility?

A small percentage in of Christians seem to hold on to this possibility.

Thus my question: **What is the teaching of the Jehovah’s Witnesses on this subject matter?**

Comment: Related  https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/2618/can-christians-be-demon-possessed?r=SearchResults

Comment: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/79610/23657     for further clarification of OP POV. See this great answer to a related Q

Comment: @Kris  Those are 2 good links! Deeply thought-provoking. RCs believe baptism (even as a baby) = born-again/Spirit anointed/member of Christ's Church; Protestants believe the Holy Spirit has first to convict and convert a person and then indwell them which joins them to Christ' 'body'; JWs believe baptised believers almost never get the anointing, indwelling Holy Spirit these days, without which a person is not a member of the spiritual 'Church'. No wonder there are so many different views on who the demons can possess, or not, and why JWs seem reluctant to clearly detail their view!

Answer (score 3):

I’m one of Jehovah’s Witnesses. We don’t believe that we are impervious to demon possession simply on the basis of being a baptized member of Jehovah’s Witnesses, but we do believe that we are impervious only if we have put on “the complete suit of armor from God.” (Eph. 6:11)

Ephesians chapter 6 goes on to define this figurative suit of armor as:

- The belt of truth fastened around your waist
- Wearing the breastplate of righteousness
- Feet shod with readiness to declare the good news of peace
- The large shield of faith
- The helmet of salvation
- The sword of the spirit, that is, God’s word

If we are wearing this suit of armor, we will “be able to stand firm against the crafty acts of the Devil” in all their forms. If someone was demon possessed, the course of action would be to inspect and fix that person’s figurative “armor,” removing anything from their life that is connected to demon activity.

I have never heard of a Jehovah’s Witness getting possessed by a demon, but it would be possible if that person had strayed from the faith and no longer came under God’s protection.

See the article, [“Can the Devil Control Humans?”](https://www.jw.org/finder?wtlocale=E&docid=502013281&srcid=share) for more info.

Comment: Your straightforward, clear answer is appreciated. But when you claim, "We don’t believe that we are impervious to demon possession simply on the basis of being a baptized member of Jehovah’s Witnesses", you don't offer any JW sources for that. Could you possibly cite, and quote the official view there? That would be appreciated.

Comment: @Anne I have now added a link to an article as a reference. Baptism is not one of the suggestions for protection from demons. Demon possession is rarely discussed in JW literature.

Comment: *I have never heard of a Jehovah’s Witness getting possessed by a demon, but it would be possible if that person had strayed from the faith and no longer came under God’s protection.* - have you ever heard of a **non**-JW getting possessed by a demon? How do JWs deal with **non**-JWs who are demon possessed?

Comment: @Spirit The scriptures in the linked article apply for non-JWs alike. Once a man came to my Kingdom Hall who said he was being disturbed by the demons and was looking for help. The elders in my congregation spoke with him privately after the meeting and conducted a Bible study with him. I remember another occasion in a different congregation where someone was directed to also seek medical care because it was more of a mental disorder.

Comment: @4castle - do you know if JWs have ever had to deal with cases such as these: [1](https://youtu.be/Mkdaz6dVRO4?t=177), [2](https://youtu.be/4rOYVuI6dXg?t=11), [3](https://youtu.be/mAQevnUDU24), [4](https://youtu.be/pIqPfZZOQsg?t=48)?

Comment: @Spirit No, but generally JWs don’t discuss cases of demon activity because it can be counterproductive, but here is a video that explained how a family got relief. https://www.jw.org/finder?srcid=share&prefer=content&applanguage=E&locale=en&item=pub-jwb_201908_3_VIDEO&docid=1011214

Comment: Thanks for that link but it does not deal with the question of whether a baptised JW could ever become demon possessed. There is surely a difference between suffering demonic harassment/attempts to mislead, and actual demon-possession (as per descriptions in the NT)? Examples given by you (especially that video link) are of non-JWs getting help to study and do the things listed in that previous link. JW "Baptism symbolizes dying to one's former way of life and becoming alive to do God's will" (Bible Teach p183) so those not baptised as JWs cannot be viewed as pleasing God, and open to attack?

Comment: @anne the answer addresses the question.  If you have additional questions ask them in a new question.

Comment: @Kris  Well, I’m still wondering why nothing in JW literature about a baptised JW becoming demon possessed has been cited yet, but your advice is good, and I shall take it.

Comment: @Anne I agree with Anne that it deals with demonic oppression and not demonic possession. The two are clear distinct manners in which evil sprits operate amongst mankind.

Comment: @Kris My question clearly refers to **demonic possession**!

Comment: @Anne I haven't cited anything specifically about a baptized JW becoming demon possessed because I've never read an article that made a distinction between JWs and non-JWs in the matter. Those instructions that are given to non-JWs say nothing about getting baptized, so I would assume that the instructions would help JWs just the same. It's the spiritual "suit of armor" that protects from demon possession, irrespective of a person being baptized.

Comment: @ 4castle Yes, I’ve noted that in the few examples I’ve seen in JW lit. & videos, but the people suffering demonic harassment were always interested people, studying with JWs and unbaptised, or a baptised JW with a non-JW partner or relative who turned out to be the ‘link’. Yet the spiritual ‘suit of armour’ can only be utilised by baptised Christians, so I understand. An atheist, for example, could never put it on! See my Q further to the matter https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/83609/would-jehovah-s-witnesses-anointed-with-the-holy-spirit-be-unable-to-suffer-demo

Comment: @Anne The spiritual suit of armor can be used by more than just people who are baptized. It could be utilized by unbaptized publishers also, or even by Bible students who have not yet requested to be recognized as an unbaptized publisher, but who are ready to share the good news with their friends or family (remember the "feet shod with readiness to declare the good news of peace"). The correlation that you're recognizing is that putting on the spiritual suit of armor has basically the same requirements as the qualifications for baptism.

Answer (score 1):

My sister is demon possessed and was baptized at 16. She married into a family that practices witchcraft when she wasn’t an active witness. Although active again, she is still possessed.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Are you also an active Witness? What is she doing now that makes her active? Has she approached the elders for help? What did the elders say she should do? How do you know that she is still demon possessed? More details would be helpful. You can [edit] to improve your answer.