# Are there video recordings of humans said to be possessed by demons?

Tags: history, demon-possession, technology

Are there video recordings of humans said to be possessed by demons? Has a claimed demon possession ever been recorded on camera? I'm open to answers from any Christian groups/denominations.

---

Related or similar questions:

- [Are people possessed by demons today? What is the modern Christian perspective?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/2614/50422)
- [Has an angel or a demon ever been recorded on camera?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/91832/50422)
- [Has a healing miracle ever been recorded on camera?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/83624/50422)
- [How do continuationists explain the absence of video recordings of undeniable miracles?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/84586/50422)

Comment: Possibly - but if the demon was not visible to mortal eyes, how would having it on camera distinguish between the real thing and somebody just acting?  Maybe I'm misunderstanding what you are asking, but it seems like a video would give more opportunity for deception than seeing it live.

Comment: @HoldToTheRod: `but if the demon was not visible to mortal eyes, how would having it on camera distinguish between the real thing and somebody just acting?` -That's a good question. Some additional information would be required to discount alternative hypotheses, such as acting, mental illness or pretty advanced CGI. I'm asking with the expectation that there could be at least one case where the video of a possession is accompanied by good enough contextual information to discount alternative hypotheses.

Comment: @HoldToTheRod: `Maybe I'm misunderstanding what you are asking, but it seems like a video would give more opportunity for deception than seeing it live.` - Seeing a (supposed) demon possession live still faces the alternative explanations of acting and mental illness. You can be quite confident though that the possession you are witnessing with your own eyes live is very likely not CGI, I can grant you that :-)

Comment: For sure, opportunities for deception still exist in person (albeit not all the same opportunities). Thanks for clarifying. I don't know of any examples that would meet your specific criteria.

Comment: Having been  personally in the presence of possessed individuals, I know that there are times it is impossible to know that they are actually possessed unless the Demon is forced to show his presence. I am convinced that such individuals could be photographed and we would not be any the wiser that they were truly possessed. Such photographic images certainly exist. But would others believe?

Comment: I don't understand how this is any less opinion based than your question: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/91832/has-an-angel-or-a-demon-ever-been-recorded-on-camera

Comment: Whether or not someone views a person as demon possessed is completely arbitrary to their own views on the topic of demons. Therefore it's impossible (at least on this site) to answer your question in an objective way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Are there video recordings of humans said to be possessed by demons?**

I would venture to say that such video recordings do exist, but the question implies several problems that are inherent to the supernatural, that is to say above the natural way of thing that man is accustomed to in life and understand it as such.

- Demons have no physical form and can not take on a human form in the absolute sense of the word. They can possess individuals physically, but their souls he can not be  possessed.
- They may appear to individuals in some form or other through the usage of one’s imagination, but he can not take on a human nature properly speaking.
- Individuals who have been genuinely diagnosed (and I am speaking of those who have been to a Catholic Exorcist and have been evaluated also by medical professionals such as doctors, and psychiatrists, etc. in order to eliminate all other possibilities) may seem quite normal in most of their dealings with people. The Devil never wants to make himself obvious.  He prefers to lurk in the shadows knowing that his prey is his possession and could possibly lead these souls into despair.
- Even though some (Christian) groups may claim that they have video recording of individuals who are possessed, what is the threshold of scientific or theological proofs that such recordings are in fact genuine.

I am convinced that such video recordings do exist, I would always be sceptical of such recordings, as there is no actual criteria to evaluate such things.

There exists a DVD entitled [The Exorcist in the 21st Century](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2351393/plotsummary?ref_=tt_ov_pl) (2012) which shows several individuals claiming to be possessed. The bonus features has a “real exorcism” performed by a Catholic bishop. I am skeptical of some things in the video, but will admit that some of the individuals interviewed are probably the “***Real McCoy***”.

You are free to discern it for yourself if you wish. I desire to remain neutral in this as best as possible.

Comment: The filmmaker of *The Devil and Father Amorth* claims his movie recorded a truly possessed woman https://www.vulture.com/2018/04/william-friedkin-on-the-terror-of-filming-an-actual-exorcism-in-the-devil-and-father-amorth.html

Answer (score 1):

## Yes, according to some Christian groups.

There are a number of Christian groups that claim that homosexuality is caused by demonic influence, and [perform exorcisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gay_exorcism) to try to drive away the demons responsible for it.

Since there are a number of videos of events like gay pride parades, it then follows that those groups of Christians would regard them as videos of people possessed by demons.

Comment: Can you add references to your answer?

Comment: @SpiritRealmInvestigator I added a link to a Wikipedia article. Does that help?

Comment: Yes,,, it does!